# Why does Angular 13 webpack build fail?

Tags: angular-cli, webpack-4, angular13

I am currently trying to migrate an application from Angular 12 to 13 .
I am using webpack `4.43.0` in package.json (devDependecies) :

```
"webpack": "^4.43.0",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
"webpack-merge": "^4.1.2"
```

I had manually migrated all the required libraries to their corresponding version 13 and then when I run `npm run start` (`start` is the script present in the app ) to transpile and serve the code in the application, I keep getting the below errors :

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2015/http.mjs
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/common' in 'C:\Kunal\node_modules\@angular\common\fesm2015'

ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm2015/forms.mjs
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/common' in 'C:\Kunal\node_modules\@angular\forms\fesm2015'

ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm2015/platform-browser-dynamic.mjs
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/common' in 'C:\Kunal\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser-dynamic\fesm2015'

ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm2015/platform-browser.mjs
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/common' in 'C:\Kunal\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\fesm2015'

ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/router/fesm2015/router.mjs
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/common' in 'C:\Kunal\node_modules\@angular\router\fesm2015'

ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm2015/platform-browser-dynamic.mjs
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/compiler' in 'C:\Kunal\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser-dynamic\fesm2015'

-------- etc.
```

I am not understanding what I am doing wrong here . Can someone advice me as to what I should be doing here ?

**Note :**  My node version is :16.13.0 and npm version is : 8.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the angular team , webpack 4 is not compatible with Angular 13 . We moved to webpack 5 and that resolved the issue .

Refer : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/46795